# Spacing between navigation links

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I want to have spacing between the navigation links. I have searched over the internet but all I get are reducing the space. 
To be specific, I want to have spacing in between each navigation link that are bordered with a black border.

These are my codes for the navigation bar. I would really appreciate some help. thank you.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #000;
 }

 li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px; 
    text-decoration: none;
 }

 li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000; 
 }

li:last-child {
     border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's what `margin` is for.

Comment: I tried the margin and I couldnt fix it

Comment: Please clarify your **specific** problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add margin-bottom:5px; to your li

Answer (score 0):

You need to use margin to add the white space, but the borders needed a little tweaking, see comments below

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /*border: 5px solid #000; moved to LI element*/
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;  
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom:10px; /*add some margin to create the white space*/
  border: 5px solid #000; /*add the border to each LI element rather than UL*/
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  /*border-bottom: 5px solid #000; remove this bottom border as handled in    LI css*/
}
```

Comment: comments using `//` are invalid CSS syntax, use `/* */` instead.

Comment: sorry, yes, so used to using scss

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    }

 li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;  
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    }
 li {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
li:last-child {
     margin-bottom:0;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
</style>



<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/4fLbx4xa/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>

           <style> 
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                position: fixed;
                margin-top: 50px;
                padding: 0;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: #fff;
                }

             li{
               width:100%;
                display: block;
                margin-top:10px; //this is the height you want
                 border: 5px solid #000; 
                 color: #000;
                 background:#000;
                 padding:10px 0;
                }
             li  a  {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px 16px;  
                text-decoration: none;
                color:#fff;
            }

            li:first-child {
                margin-top:0;
            }

            li:hover {
                background-color: #555;
                color: white;
            }
    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want to achieve but i understood a line between the links, this might help you also if you want it below the links..

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #000;}

 li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;  
    text-decoration: none;}
 li {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border-right:solid 1px black;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
```